# json to dataframe conversion / Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, api

I just imported an API to get the exchange rate of Taiwan dollar (TWD) with other currencies.
So I import it with this code :

```
import requests
r=requests.get('http://api.cambio.today/v1/full/TWD/json?key=X')
dico = r.json()
```

And it gives me:

```
{'result': {'from': 'TWD',
  'conversion': [{'to': 'AED',
    'date': '2020-06-23T07:23:49',
    'rate': 0.124169},
   {'to': 'AFN', 'date': '2020-06-23T07:19:53', 'rate': 2.606579},
   {'to': 'ALL', 'date': '2020-06-19T20:48:10', 'rate': 3.74252},
   {'to': 'AMD', 'date': '2020-06-22T12:00:19', 'rate': 16.176679},
   {'to': 'AOA', 'date': '2020-06-22T12:32:59', 'rate': 20.160418},
   {'to': 'ARS', 'date': '2020-06-23T08:00:01', 'rate': 2.363501}
  ]}
}
```

To turn it into a dataframe I tried two things:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dico.get('result', {}))
```

and

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
dictr = r.json()
df = json_normalize(dictr)
```

In both cases, I end up with a "conversion" column with one line per currency. For example the first line is: "{'to': 'AFN', 'date': '2020-06-23T07:19:53', 'rate': 2.606579}".
While I would like to have one column for the currency and one for the exchange rate.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: could you please paste valid json. I am pretty sure there are typos here

Answer (score 1):

The json you pasted is not valid json. But I guess the format of the json should be this one

```
{'result': {'from': 'TWD',
  'conversion': [{'to': 'AED',
    'date': '2020-06-23T07:23:49',
    'rate': 0.124169},
   {'to': 'AFN', 'date': '2020-06-23T07:19:53', 'rate': 2.606579},
   {'to': 'ALL', 'date': '2020-06-19T20:48:10', 'rate': 3.74252},
   {'to': 'AMD', 'date': '2020-06-22T12:00:19', 'rate': 16.176679},
   {'to': 'AOA', 'date': '2020-06-22T12:32:59', 'rate': 20.160418},
   {'to': 'ARS', 'date': '2020-06-23T08:00:01', 'rate': 2.363501}]}}
```

In that case to create dataframe you want you can use

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dico.get('result', {}).get('conversion', {}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do get the `"conversion"` property value with the list of conversion rates, use this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dico["result"]["conversion"])
```

It will format your conversion data like this:

```
    to  date                rate
0   AED 2020-06-23T07:23:49 0.124169
1   AFN 2020-06-23T07:19:53 2.606579
2   ALL 2020-06-19T20:48:10 3.742520
3   AMD 2020-06-22T12:00:19 16.176679
4   AOA 2020-06-22T12:32:59 20.160418
5   ARS 2020-06-23T08:00:01 2.363501
```